# tables are not aligning to the top of the page

Tags: php, html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

### my code:

---

### achieved with the following code :

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
echo '<table><tr>';
$folders = @scandir('Users');  
     foreach($folders as $item):
     if ((substr($item, 0, 1) == '.') || (preg_match("/\.php$/", $item)))
                continue;
    ?>
    <td>
          <table width="220" border="1" valign="top">
               <tr><th width="210" valign="top"><?php echo $item;?></th></tr>
              <?php
               if (is_dir("Users/$item"))
            $target_folders = @scandir("Users/$item/uploaded/");
                foreach($target_folders as $target_item){

                if ((!preg_match("/^[.]/",$target_item)) || (!is_dir("Users/$item/uploaded/$target_item"))){
                if ((substr($target_item, 0, 1) == '.'))
                   continue;     

                   ?><tr><td><?php echo $target_item ;?></td></tr><?php

                }
                }

                   ?>
          </table>
</td>
    <?php
endforeach;

echo '</tr></table>';
?>



</body>
</html>
```

---

Now for the life of me i cant get the data that is displayed to align to the top of the page. i really don't know what i am doing wrong here but i do know that it is probably something simple.

a link to what i am displaying :
[Current Code Outcome](http://ccrxpersonnel.com/maindisplay2.php)

Comment: Why do you have a table within a table? Im going to guess its because you have a table within the other table.

Comment: i do realize that the setup looks a little weird but the result i needed was to display data by columns instead of rows and this is what i came up with to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add follownig in style sheet

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

regards

Comment: you can also add top !important; if above do not work, though i have checked on your page it is working.

Comment: damn i knew it was something this simple too. thank you very much.

Comment: [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025061/start-new-column-when-readdir-moves-to-new-dir/19029193#19029193) do you think you could up vote this for me?

Answer (score 0):

try
align td as top instead of table valign - top

Answer (score 0):

posting since I wrote it anyway and then you changed the question content

1. <s>present a jfiddle.net with actual rendered html</s>,
2. explain why you are using such a complex doctype
3. try

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kG7B4/

```
td { vertical-align:top }
```